# How to customize the editor interface in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to develop a vscode plug-in, but I need to customize the editing interface view to be the same as the compare file interface that comes with vscode (the editing function remains the same, only the custom editing interface is required). What should I need to do, thank you

View effect: (One tab and two editing windows)

[image]

Comment: the diff windows are already editable

Comment: I want to add some specific operations on this basis，

Comment: Can you give me some inspiration? Do I need to use webview+custom Editors? If I write the interface myself, how should I keep the original code prompt highlighting and other functions?

Comment: do you need the specific diff functionality or just two editors in one tab, The easiest thing to do is to split the window and open 2 files in the 2 columns and sync the "show" of the editors if one of them gets the focus